# Rich Snippet appears in Google's testing tool, but does not appear in Google Search

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, schema.org

I have created [a simple test page](http://livehire.me/test/) to test Schema.org Microdata.

When [tested in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://livehire.me/test/) it appears as it should, displaying the address and job title below the green URL in the search result.

Now when I test this in Google, the address and job title are not displayed and it’s as if the Microdata is not there at all.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: After more researching a lot of people on the Google Help forums are saying it can take up to 4-8 weeks for Google to put use to the Microdata...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does take time for Google to crawl your site and for rich snippets to appear in your search results, as indicated here:

[Google Webmaster Tools - Rich snippets not appearing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493?hl=en)

Review the checklist there, and after a few weeks if it still doesn't appear, then use the form here to let Google know:

[Google Webmaster Tools - Rich snippets feedback](https://support.google.com/webmasters/contact/rich_snippets_feedback)

You may also use the Fetch As Google tool to trigger crawling, as covered here:

[Google Webmaster Tools - Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en)